# row(this).data().id is undefined using Responsive extension

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using jQuery DataTables with Responsive extension. It works fine when there is no child row, but when the row collapses I cannot get the row id. Here's my code:

```
$('#mytable').on( 'click', 'tr', function (e) {
    var rowid = tbl.row( this ).data().id; // it will be undefined when the row collapses
});
```